# Implementing message priority in AMQP

Tags: message-queue, amqp

I'm intending to use AMQP to allow a distributed collection of machines to report to a central location asynchronously.  The idea is to drop messages into the queue and allow the central logging entity to process the queue in a decoupled fashion; the 'process' is simply to create or update a row in a database table.

A problem that I'm anticipating is the effect of network jitter in the message queuing process - what happens if an `update` accidentally gets in front of an `insert` because the time between the two messages being issued is less than the network jitter?

Reading the AMQP spec, it seems that I could just apply a higher priority to `insert`s so they skip the queue and get processed first.  But presumably this only applies if a queue actually exists at the broker to be skipped.  Is there a way to impose a buffer or delay at the broker to absorb this jitter and allow priority to be enacted before the messages are passed on to the consumer(s)?

Or do I have to go down the route of a resequencer [as ActiveMQ suggests](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lack of ordering between multiple publishers has nothing to do with network jitter, it's a completely natural thing in distributed applications. Messages from the same publisher will always be ordered. If you really need causal ordering of actions performed by different nodes then either a resequencer or a global sequence numbering scheme are your only options. Note that you **cannot** use sender timestamps for this, which is what everyone seems to try first..

Comment: Thanks Holger. When you say "messages from the same publisher will always be ordered" - is this dependent on the implementation of AMQP in use?

Comment: I think it's part of the spec - anything else would be very surprising. Should be easy to find.